# Highlight Cell in one Column BASED on Conditional Formatting of Other Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner with Macros. I slightly changed my code below to include conditional formatting based on an Input Value.  The code below applies a conditional format (orange highlight) to 6 specific columns based on whether those columns contain a specific text. I would like to add another step after this coding where the cells of another column (column B) are highlighted in a different color (yellow) if ANY of the 6 columns contain the orange highlighted conditional formatting.

So for example - In Row 2, if any of the 6 columns contain the conditional formatting of an orange highlight, then B2 will be highlighted in yellow.

Is there a similar formula which would work with an input value instead of including the search term within the formula? I don't know whether the solution lies in a specific formula or if I need to use an if and then statement instead.

I've searched other online posts and there does seem to be a way to check whether a cell has conditional formatting by searching for a cell's Formatted Interior Color. I'm trying to create an If and then statement which checks all 6 columns per row and if I can get the specific row number - maybe I can apply the yellow highlighting to the 2nd cell of that row number.

Please let me know if anyone has any further suggestions.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Since you have a table, you don't need code for your ask. You can just apply the conditional formatting directly to the table. Use formula as an option and the formula will be something like `=OR(IsNumber(Search(tbl[Overall Description],"concrete")),IsNumber(Search(tbl[Description of Work],"concrete")...`

Comment: I kept getting a message saying there's a problem with this formula.  Is there a similar formula which would work with an input value instead of including the search term within the formula?

Comment: use `Search("concrete",tbl[Overall Description])` instead, I was only writing an example and got the syntax wrong. Also note you'll need to make adjustments for your table name, etc. What I provided was concept only for you to play with.